# How to get Amazon campaign

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

There are many resources about how to receive of Android Play Store campaign.

Like
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-campaigns

With this guide we can receive information from where did user installed our application.

But how to know if application was installed from Amazon App Store ? I didn't found any guide about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. We just take installer package.

```
private static boolean isAmazonInstaller(Context ctx) {
        String installer = ctx.getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName(ctx.getPackageName());

        return installer!=null && installer.equals("com.amazon.venezia");
    }
```